# does geckodriver in selenium comes with firefox or do we need to install it separately?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, geckodriver

I am working to deploy my selenium code on remote server. Wondering if Gecko driver in Selenium comes with Firefox or do we need to install it separately on server?

Comment: What have you done to investigate your wondering if it comes with it?

Comment: formating and spelling

Answer (score 1):

It does not come with firefox. You can download it from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/)

You can put geckodriver into your project directory and map it to your code so no need to install it on the remote machine.

Please refer below code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.geckodriver.driver",
                        System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\ur path\\geckodriver.exe");
```